# How can I reset Location Warnings in the iOS simulator on Lion?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode

Referring to the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337569/re-enable-iphone-%E2%80%A6), how can I reset warnings for locations in Mac OS X Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lion didn't change your Xcode or iPhone simulator.

Xcode 4.1 / iOS Simulator 4.3 has rolled that into the resetting the simulated device.[image]